# BART finetune run_train.sh generates models with performance issues

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I have run the run_train.sh script at and at steps of 75000, the model still couldn't produce a decent summary.

Here is an example summary generated from model trained from run_train.sh which is still so broken:
Kimberly� have else  better' she). am New other" on aag like.) in when, - d you,'] first her A what Kim Thef into here or the said has'm herself Former NBC came In will one Women '- to around there  can at another Woman Produ ab it had," out no up are], new be isar? [. that doit

I do notice the "(WIP) Rouge Scores" at https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/summarization/bart. I wonder if the fine-tune code is finished with model performance verified.

Answer (score 0):

Need to set output_past to true in the model configuration. For details, please see https://github.com/microsoft/nlp-recipes/pull/591